# Upload source map to Bugsnag for VUE JS

Tags: vue.js, source-maps, bugsnag

For my VUE JS ( VUE CLI) application, I have uploaded a source map to Bugsnag using webpack-bugsnag-plugins. But I am wondering if there is any way that the source map is not shown in the browser. I tried deleting the created *.map files after uploading to bugsnag in the post-build script, but then the error event is not mapped to the source file in Bugsnag.

I am worried about exposing my source code in the browser with productionSourceMap = true, but I wanted to have the full trace of my error in Bugsnag.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This was successful! After sometime Bugsnag started to show full stack trace correctly.

Comment: would be great if you could add your own answer with some of the details. Having a Laravel Vue application and would love to see how you set things up.